# Slick 2.0 and IntelliJ, highlighting errors

Tags: scala, slick

I'm in the process of migrating to Slick 2.0.0-RC1 (from 1.x), and I'm having trouble getting IntelliJ to recognize the lifted embedding implicits around the `TableQuery` statements.  However, everything *does* compile, in both IntelliJ and sbt (read: play).  I started by leveraging the new code generation feature, and just now I grabbed snippets from slick-examples verbatim — both produce the same behavior.

Using the first example of lifted embedding (https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/FirstExample.scala) the following two things occur:

- The line:

  ```
  def supplier = foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, suppliers)(_.id)
  ```

  Produces an error on `suppliers` saying `Type mismatch, expected: TableQuery[NotInferredTT], actual: ((Tag) => FirstExample.Suppliers) => TableQuery[FirstExample.Suppliers]`
- The `TableQuery[...]` vals (e.g., coffees) don't have any of the lifted collection-like operations on them (e.g., filter, map, take, etc.).

Weirdly enough, using for-comprehensions doesn't produce any errors, however nothing has the right type information (ends up as an `Any`).

I'm positive that I've got the `.simple._` import (it doesn't compile elsewhere without it).  I've cleared all my caches, rerun my gen-idea, done full rebuilds, etc. with no progress.  I'm running IntelliJ 12.1.6 Ultimate with the Scala 0.22.302 plugin.  My own project uses SQLServer, but I tried the example with H2 and experienced the same thing.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Upon further inspection, it looks like macro isn't working within IntelliJ — if I explicitly type out a constructor lambda for the `TableQuery` (e.g., `val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers](tag => new Suppliers(tag))`), everything starts working as expected.  Am I doing something stupid here?

Comment: also posted here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaquery/bHUj0Sc2Ne8/ypZK1Pgf4dsJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack to get around this, but I'm really looking for something more robust.  If I override `SourceCodeGenerator`, and then override the `TableDef` inside that, and then override the `TableValueDef` inside that, I can override the `def code` inside that to this:

```
override def code = s"lazy val $name = TableQuery[${TableClass.name}](tag => new ${TableClass.name}(tag))"
```

...and then I don't have problems with the macro not evaluating.  It goes without saying that this isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: Thx. I committed a PR to change the default code generator accordingly. https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/595

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just suppressing the error but calling it directly in the function worked for me:

```
foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, TableQuery[Suppliers])
```